# ¿Alguien sabe como puedo cambiar el valor de una variable cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: c, array

Estoy haciendo una simulacion de una plataforma de inversionistas y tengo variables donde se guardan "acciones de bolsa", el inversionista se registra y accede a un menu donde hay una opcion de ver las cotizaciones, lo que quiero hacer es que la cotizacion cambie cada 2 minutos.
Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define cls system("cls")  /*LIMPIAR LA PANTALLA*/
    #define flush fflush(stdin) /*LIMPIA LA MEMORIA (SE UTILIZA CUANDO SE SCANEAN VALORES CHAR Y COMIENZA A ARROJAR DATOS BASURA*/
    #define pause system("pause") //PAUSA EN LA PANTALLA

    int pos=-1; /*VARIABLE PARA CONTROLAR LA POSICION DEL INDICE AL MOMENTO DE HACER REGISTROS*/
    int i; /*VARIABLE QUE GUARDA LA POSICION DEL INDICE AL INICIAR SESION (UTILIZAR PARA ACCEDER A CUALQUIER INFORMACION DEL INVERSIONISTA)*/
    int acceso = 0; /*BANDERA PARA PODER ACCEDER AL MENU DEL INVERSIONISTA*/
    float monedas[5]; //VECTOR PARA ALMACENAR LOS PRECIOS DE LAS MONEDAS
    char nombres[5][15] = {"BITCOIN","ETHEREUM","RIPPLE","LITECOIN","DASH"}; //NOMBES DE LAS CRIPTOMONEDAS

    struct traders /*ESTRUCTURA DEL INVERSIONISTA CON SUS ATRIBUTOS*/
    {
        char usuario[20],password[20]; //Datos para inicio de sesion
        float balance, status; //Datos de inversion
    }investor[5]; //Arreglo de 5 inversionistas

    float random()//FUNCION QUE GENERA NUMEROS ALEATORIOS FLOTANTES
    {
        float a = 10/*ESTA VARIABLE ES EL NUMERO MAXIMO AL QUE GENERA NUMEROS ALEATORIOS, EN ESTE CASO DE 0 - 10*/,ran;
        int x;
        for(x=0;x<4;x++)
            ran = ((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
        return ran; //SE RETORNA EL ULTIMO VALOR DE FOR PARA OBTENER NUMEROS QUE VARIEN MAS
    }

    void registrar()//FUNCION PARA REGISTRAR NUEVOS USUARIOS
    {
        cls;
        if(pos<4)
        {
            pos++;
            printf("\t---------------------REGISTRARSE-------------------- ");
            printf("\nUsuario: ");scanf("%s",&investor[pos].usuario);
            printf("Contrase%ca: ",164);scanf("%s",&investor[pos].password);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NO SE ADMITEN MAS REGISTROS\n");
        }
    }

    void mostrar()//FUNCION PARA MOSTRAR LOS USUARIOS REGISTRADOS
    {
        cls;
        int j;
        if(pos==-1)
        {
            printf("AUN NO HAY REGISTROS\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\t---------------------USUARIOS REGISTRADOS--------------------\n");
            for(j=0;j<=pos;j++)
            {
                printf("Usuario: %s \n",investor[j].usuario);
                printf("Contrase%ca: %s\n",164,investor[j].password);
                printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    }

    void login() //FUNCION PARA INICIO DE SESION, COMPRUEBA QUE USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA COINCIDAN
    {
        cls;
        char user[20],pass[20]; //Datos para comparar con los que estan en la estructura
        int band=0;
        printf("\t---------------------INICIAR SESION-------------------- ");
        if(pos==-1)
        {
            printf("\n\nAUN NO HAY REGISTROS PARA INICIO DE SESION\n");
            pause;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nUsuario: ");scanf("%s",&user);
            printf("Contrase%ca: ",164);scanf("%s",&pass);
            for(i=0;i<=pos;i++)
            {
                if(strcmp(user,investor[i].usuario)==0 && strcmp(pass,investor[i].password)==0)
                {
                    printf("\nIniciando sesion.......\n");
                    acceso = 1;
                    band++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(band==0)
                printf("\nEL USUARIO O CONTRASE%cA NO COINCIDEN\n",165);
                pause;
        }
    }

    void cotizacion()
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++)
            monedas[i] = random();
    }


    int main()
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL)); //INICIADOR PARA NUMEROS ALEATORIOS
        int op; //OPCION PARA NAVEGAR EN LOS MENUS
        do
        {
            cls;
            printf("\t\t---------------------BIT TRADER-------------------- \n1)Iniciar Sesion \n2)Registrarse \n3)Mostrar usuarios/contrase%cas \n4)Salir \n: ",164); //MENU PRINCIPAL
            flush;
            scanf("%d",&op);
            switch(op)//MENU PRINCIPAL
            {
                case 1:
                    login();
                    if(acceso==1) //SI USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA COINCIDEN SE PASA EL MENU DEL INVERSIONISTA
                    {
                            do{
                                cls;
                                cotizacion();
                                Sleep(2000);
                                printf("\t\t---------------------Bienvenido %s-------------------- \n1)Ver cotizaciones \n2)Depositar a tu cuenta \n3)Invertir \n4)Ver balance actual \n5)Reporte \n6)Cerrar sesion \n: ",investor[i].usuario,164);//Menu del inversionista
                                flush;
                                scanf("%d",&op);
                                switch(op)//MENU DE INVERSIONISTA
                                { 
                                    case 1:
                                        cls;
                                        printf("\t\t---------------------COTIZACIONES--------------------\n");
                                        int j;
                                        for(j=0; j<5; j++)
                                        {
                                            printf("%s: ",nombres[j]);
                                            printf("%.2f\n",monedas[j]);
                                        }
                                        printf("\n");

                                        pause;
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        printf("\t\t---------------------DEPOSITAR A TU CUENTA--------------------\n");
                                        pause;
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        printf("\t\t---------------------INVERTIR--------------------\n");
                                        pause;
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        printf("\t\t---------------------BALANCE ACTUAL--------------------\n");
                                        pause;
                                        break;
                                    case 5:
                                        printf("\t\t---------------------REPORTE--------------------\n");
                                        pause;
                                        break;
                                    case 6: //CIERRA SESION Y REGRESA AL MENU PRINCIPAL
                                        printf("\nCerrando sesion....\n");
                                        pause;
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        printf("\nOpcion incorrecta, prueba de nuevo\n");
                                        pause;}
                                }while(op != 6);
                    }
                    acceso = 0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    registrar();
                    pause;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mostrar();
                    pause;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf("\nVuelva pronto....\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("\nOpcion incorrecta, prueba de nuevo\n");
                    pause;
            }
        }while (op != 4);
        return 0;
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el contenido del siguiente enlace: [ask], en SO existen reglas de como preguntar, y una de ellas es que debes intentar resolver tu problema.

Comment: ¿Quieres datos reales o generar datos aleatorios?

Comment: Ya tengo una funcion para generar valores flotantes aleatorios, solo necesito "refrescar esos valores" cada cierto tiempo

Comment: colocalo dentro de un while(true){tu_tarea(); sleep(periodo);}

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer para poder ir cambiando el valor y no dormir tu programa es hacerlo en un hilo a parte, pasándole la variable por referencia. En el nuevo hilo es donde debes hacer un while(true) sleep(tiempo). Así no bloquearás el hilo principal de tu programa y te irá variando el valor de la variable.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano ¿Sabes cómo puedo hacerlo en segundo plano?

Comment: Lo que te he dicho, lo tienes que hacer con hilos, aquí tienes un ejemplo: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f96/uso-threads-c-1122642/

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es guardar una marca de tiempo y consultar, antes de imprimir los valores, si han pasado más de dos minutos desde la última marca de tiempo... si es afirmativo actualizas los valores:

```
time_t marcaDeTiempo = 0;

// ...

time_t actual = time(NULL);
if( actual - marcaDeTiempo >= 120 ) // time_t almacena segundos
{
  // actualizamos la marca de tiempo
  marcaDeTiempo = actual;

  // actualizar valores
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función `Sleep();` (valor en milisegundos) para poder utilizarla debes agregar la liberería `#include <windows.h>` , para poner 2 minutos = 120 segundos => Sleep(120000);
O puedes hacer que presionando una tecla se cambien los valores (utiliza enter '\n'), utiliza `srand(time(NULL));` para definir random en funcion del tiempo, y agregas los valores con `int valor = rand();`

Espero haberte ayudado. Pon el código del programa que tienes hecho para que te podamos ayudar un poco más.

Comment: Trate de utilizar sleep, pero me detiene la ejecucion de los menus hasta que pasa el tiempo que se le indicó, estoy tratanto que el menu del inversionista la cotizacion este cambiando en tiempo real cada 2 minutos pero sin afectar la ejecucion de las opciones que tiene, acabo de poner el codigo, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Claro, si te entiendo es que el _Sleep_ como el nombre lo indica "Duerme" el programa y lo que tu necesitas es hacerlo en segundo plano. Quizás podrías utilizarlo en una función aparte: `void tiempo(){...Sleep...}` pero no se si funcionará.