# Guardar hora local en una variable

Tags: c, datetime

Estoy tratando de guardar la hora de registro en una variable, por ejemplo, si el sistema registra una ejecución del programa a las 3am necesito que se guarde en una variable, pero si imprimo el valor de esa variable en cualquier otro momento siempre me muestre las 3am

```
int *tiempo;
time_t currentTime = time(NULL);
time(&currentTime);
struct tm *myTime = localtime(&currentTime);
tiempo = myTime->tm_sec;
printf("Tiempo en segundos actual: %d\n", myTime->tm_sec);
printf("Tiempo registrado: %d\n", tiempo);
```

.

Comment: ¿Qué lenguajes de programación estas usando?

Comment: Los tags sirven para indicar los temas relacionados a tu pregunta, y a nosotros los que queremos ayudar a filtrar las preguntas. colocarlos adecuadamente conlleva a que la comunidad relacionada al tema de ayude rápidamente. :P

Comment: Yendo al punto, no entiendo cual es tu problema, ¿A quéte refieres que mantenga la hora? y ¿en qué momento esta cambiando?

Comment: Talvez no me explique bien, una disculpa. Por ejemplo, si el sistema registra una ejecución del programa a las 3am necesito que se guarde en una variable, pero si imprimo el valor de esa variable en cualquier otro momento siempre me muestre las 3am

Comment: Digamos que guardamos es información, y reiniciamos tu aplicación, entonces deseas que aun con eso se mantenga la variable, o solo quieres que se mantenga miestras se ejecute tu aplicación?

Comment: Solo mientras se ejecuta la aplicación

Comment: Y en qué momento se modifica el valor?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que esto es una subtarea de un programa, necesito generar un número aleatorio cada cierto tiempo sin que la ejecución del programa sea interrumpida.

Comment: Para entenderte mejor necesito que proveas un [mcve]

Comment: Aquí en esta pregunta expongo el problema completo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120990/alguien-sabe-como-puedo-cambiar-el-valor-de-una-variable-cada-cierto-tiempo-en

Comment: No te entiendo, esa pregunta es distinta a esta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tiempo = myTime->tm_sec;
```

Con esa línea estás almacenando únicamente los segundos. Si tu idea es almacenar la hora completa necesitas guardar también la hora y los minutos:

```
tiempo = myTime->tm_hour * 3600 + myTime->tm_min * 60 + myTime->tm_sec;
```

Ahora bien, dado que en `tiempo` estás almacenando la fecha codificada en segundos no tiene demasiado sentido que imprimas el valor a lo bruto:

```
printf("Tiempo registrado: %d\n", tiempo);
```

Ya que vas a devolver un valor expresado únicamente en segundos. En su lugar tendrías que tratar la variable antes de imprimirla:

```
int segundos = tiempo % 60;
tiempo /= 60;
int minutos = tiempo % 60;
int horas = tiempo / 60;

printf("Tiempo registrado: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", horas, minutos, segundos);
```

Para simplificar la tarea lo recomendable sería que trabajases con una variable de tipo `time_t` o `struct tm`. La razón es que existen funciones que te permiten imprimir y tratar las horas de forma sencilla. Por ejemplo, para imprimir la hora completa puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
struct tm tiempo = localtime(time(NULL));
char buffer[50];
strftime (buffer,50,"%H:%M:%S",tiempo);

printf("Tiempo registrado: %d\n", buffer);
```

O incluso, si tu idea es que salga lo de `am` o `pm` puedes hacer esto:

```
struct tm tiempo = localtime(time(NULL));
char buffer[50];
strftime (buffer,50,"%I:%M:%S %p",tiempo);

printf("Tiempo registrado: %d\n", buffer);
```

Así la hora se imprimirá en formato 12 horas e indicando si es por la mañana o por la tarde... y todo sin tocar apenas el código.